# Instantiated class causes website problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a file on my server called test.php. Here are the contents:

```
<?php
echo "hi\n";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', "foo", "bar");
    echo "hi\n";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error!");
}
echo "hi\n";
?>
```

The code is fairly straightforward. It should print hi three times if everything works out.

When I run this code from the shell, it does indeed print "hi" on three separate lines. However, when I access this file through the website (http://localhost/test.php), it only prints one hi.

Removing $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', "foo", "bar"); causes all three his to print successfully via website.

The MySQL information is correct and the user does have access to the database.

What would cause me accessing the file directly through the shell to print all three times, but only print once when accessed via the website?

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing "hi hi hi" on one line when viewed in a browser? The browser won't treat `"\n"` as a line-break, you need a `<br>` for that.

Comment: Yes, I initially didn't have the newlines in there, but did it to format it nicer.

Comment: when you access it from a browser, right click the page and select "view source" - I believe you'll still see the three "hi"s

Comment: I removed the newlines and still no luck. I see hihihi when running it from shell, but only one hi (even in the source) when viewing it from the browser.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Please enable it and report if you get any errors. I half suspect PDO hasn't been loaded. PHP often uses different php.ini files depending on how it is called cli, cgi, apache.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I forgot to restart httpd after installing! Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have enabled PDO extension? If you get only one "hi" it means that you get fatel error in your PDO object declaration. Something like this `"Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found"` Please check.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Your code works fine on me anyway.

Comment: This was the problem. I forgot to restart httpd after installing pdo. Silly me!